# Vector en Java, Intellij me da error y probándolo en compiladores online me corre full

Tags: java, array, intellij-idea

tengo un problema al realizar una práctica de vectores en Java, dejo el código y pantallazo:
PD. lo estoy trabajando en IntelliJ.

```
package com.aja;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Vectores {

  //Create a vector
  Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();

  //Adding elements using add() method of List
  vec.add("Tiger");
  vec.add("Lion");
  vec.add("Dog");
  vec.add("Elephant");
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás agregando valores al vector fuera de un método. Colócalas en el constructor, o bien en un bloque de inicialización de la clase.

Comment: Total, lo probē y así es, lo metí en un método y funcionó, muchas gracias

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque tiene errores de sintaxis basicos.